# Retrieving history of tracked fields odoo 11

Tags: field, odoo

I want to know how to retrieve the history of tracked fields in odoo 11, so I can use them later for statistics and maybe use graphs to display some of its significant changes and such.

I know they get displayed in the chatter below the record and its related to mail.thread, but I don't know if there's a way to get those information for other manipulations, or where they're located in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to tracked fields are stored in the `mail.tracking.value` model. You can review the table structure and methods in [`core/addons/mail/models/mail_tracking_value.py`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/mail/models/mail_tracking_value.py) (in Odoo 11.0).

You can view the Messages directly to review some of the data by going to **Settings > Technical > Email > Messages** and filtering on *Tracking values "is set"*.

The model is very basic, but you should be able to work with the message values to get your report/history data by sorting on the `mail_message_id`'s date and time.